# Button customization in Zurb's foundation

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation

Framework: Ruby on Rails.

I inserted this code into: **foundation_and_overrides.scss**

```
.button-facebook {
  $bg: #000;
  @include button($bg);
}
```

It gives me this error:

> Sass::SyntaxError at / Cannot add a number with units (0.0625em) to a
>   color (#f1f1f1).

How to customize the $bg variable in ZURB's Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this question is about Zurb Foundation 4.

According to Zurb Foundation 4 document,
`button()` mixin takes six arguments,
and button color is the second argument. Therefore you can specify button color as follows:

```
@import "foundation/components/buttons";
.button-facebook{
  $bg: #000;
  @include button($button-sml, $bg, false, false, false, false);
}
```

The first argment is padding of the button, you can use `$button-tny`, `$button-sml`, `$button-med`, `$button-lrg`, `emCalc(NNNpx)`, or whatever.

see Zurb Foundation 4 document for more detail:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html